# How to make data content provable for specific timestamp?

Tags: digital-signature

Let me explain it with an example:

Consider that timestamp of today is 1262304000000 (2010-01-01 00:00:00.00) and you have a web page (or file) with content "AAA". Content on this page may change over time however, you know you'll need to somehow *prove* that the content of the page on timestamp 1262304000000 was exactly "AAA".

Saying that services like [archive.org](https://archive.org) are not considered as a proof, what would you do to make the data provable on specific time? Is there any way at all?

Comment: Use digital signatures and trusted timestamps -  [How can I guarantee non-modification of data with signatures?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100573/how-can-i-guarantee-non-modification-of-data-with-signatures)